# Android - Handle Socket Connection in Service

Tags: android, socket.io, android-service

I tried to start socket connection and maintain it in a service. The service work well, but i cant connect to the my socket. Is it my code wrong or there some other way to do it?

This is my code

```
public class SocketService extends Service {

    private Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.91.25.99:3000");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mSocket.connect();
        mSocket.on("message", handleIncomingMessages);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Start Service",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
    private Emitter.Listener handleIncomingMessages = new Emitter.Listener(){
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args){
            System.out.println(args[0].toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"LALALALA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any errors in the logcat?

Comment: no error sir or exception

Comment: What library are you using? What device has the IP address 192.91.25.99?

Comment: i use socket.io sir, my server sir. i have server in my local network